# Datas are not printed in the view in .Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have a .Net MVC application and I have to build a frontend with JQuery, DevExpress. I have a database with datas of people and I should list them on the page.

Here is the code I tried:

The controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public JsonResult GetAllPeople()
 {
     var result = context.Persons.Select(m => m)
     return new JsonResult(Ok(result));
 }
```

And the cshtml file:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>

        var peopleList;
        function callback(response) {
            peopleList = response['value'];
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Persons/GetAllPeople",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                callback(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

        $(() => {
            $('#gridContainer').dxDataGrid({
                dataSource: peopleList,
                columns: ['lastName', 'firstName', 'address', 'dateOfBirth'],
                showBorders: true,
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

After debugging the code I can see that the 'result' object is not empty and in the 'value' field I can see the datas of the persons. While running, on the frontend the column's names are printed but the datas. Can you help me to print all the datas instead of nothing?

Comment: You're trying to eat your pizza before it's been delivered.   Your `dxDataGrid` call runs before the `$.ajax success:` callback, so at that point, "peopleList" is undefined.  Move the `.dxDataGrid` call into the callback.

Comment: Thank you, it just worked fine. I copied the code section and it's working. Thank you for your help.